# Domain Issue and Varnish Extension

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, apache

I ınstalled Nexcess Turpentine Varnish Cache extension and installed varnish 3. to my server. Configured files to listen port 8080. 
This is my Tcp check:

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5223/varnishd
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      5223/varnishd

No httpd appears as you see.

I changed default port of apache to 8080 via Cpanel>Tweak Settings.

My problem is when i try to type my address bar "solempet.com" and click enter it appears as "Default Website Page"

But when i try to type my address bar "www.solempet.com" or https://solempet.com my site loads perfectly.

It's a fresh magento installation and i setted "use secure urls" beginning at the magento installation. 
Here is some screenshots about my configuration of varnish and httpd.conf;

[image: Virtualhosts]
[image: Htpd.conf Listen Ports]

[image: Varnish default.vcl]
[image]

[image: Problem page]

Answer (score 3):

this issue is 100 years old...

first of all you need to use Turpentine vcl file, after you go to Cache Management, click save Varnish Config, will be located in

```
/home/solempet/public_html/var/default.vcl
```

to make it more easier for you, you can symlink it:

```
cd /etc/varnish
rm default.vcl
ln -s /home/solempet/public_html/var/default.vcl  ./default.vcl
```

second part, is that your backend IP address must be the same as per cPanel account configuration. configure it in Turpentine settings, in magento admin.

your Varnish startup config file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/varnish


DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T 127.0.0.1:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -p thread_pool_min=200 \
             -p thread_pool_max=4000 \
             -p thread_pool_add_delay=2 \
             -p cli_timeout=25 \
             -p cli_buffer=26384 \
             -p esi_syntax=0x2 \
             -p session_linger=100 \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,3G"
```

Comment: But it isn't solve my other problem. Thing is i cant go my magento by typing "solempet.com" it appears cpanel's default web site page.

Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:8080: Varnish admin socket timeout

Comment: your Varnish admin interface must be on 127.0.0.1:6082, and dont forget to clear your browsers cache, because cpanel error page is cached...

Comment: Failed to apply the VCL to 127.0.0.1:6082: Got unexpected response code from Varnish: 107 tmuqqtieexdjykrimbrkwfeambmxjmnc Authentication required.

Now i got this. Im completely lost here. So sorry.

Comment: I can't understand my secret key seems correct with my backend.

Comment: You may need to add a \n to the end of your secret key as stored in Magento admin. This worked for me

Comment: Error determining Varnish version: Got unexpected response code from Varnish: 500
I am not able to save varnish config.

Comment: @YogeshTrivedi Did you manage to fix that?

Comment: Yes, i have posted answer below, try it and let me know if everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

If its dedicated server then you wont need to host on the real IP

I assume that varnish is installed on 127.0.0.1

So just change `<Virtual host`> entry from real ip to local server 127.0.0.1

Change

```
<VirtualHost 185.22.187.220:8080>
```

to

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
```

If its not working then run `netstat -tulpn` and let me know the results so I can look more into it.

Restart the server... in my case i am using Nginx, and question asked in this thread is for Apache so i have posted answer for Apache only.